# Is there a way to change the keyboard layout in Vim on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, keyboard-layout

I am working on several documents where I have to type `[` `]` `{` and the like (which is much easier with with an american keyboard layout (and to which I am used much more)) but where I also have to type Umlauts such as ä, ö and ü.

Usually, I go be setting up the (what I believe to be a standard) Windows Shortcut `Alt+Shift` to switch between these layouts.

This is unpractical, because at times I am not sure if I am already in the german layout when I need the german layout (and vice versa).

So, is there a better way to change the keyboard layout in Vim on *OS-level"?

I guess it could be solved with changed `:map` and `:imap` but I'd rather not use these for such porposes unless really forced to.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to ask how to type Umlauts more easily. I assume you're using `Ctrl-k``:``a`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such an option - even though vim can even make pancake for you!
It'd be highly unlikely for *any* program to allow changing the keyboard layout of regular keys since basically any OS already supports it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if I am already in the german layout when I need the german layout

Do you have the language bar enabled? It should have an icon that represents your current settings.

Microsoft Knowledgebase article: [HOW TO: Use the Language Bar in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306993)

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing that you need is to add umlauts easily, Vim has built-in support for adding these characters:

**Method 1.** In insert mode type: `CTRL-K a:` to give ä.
**Method 2.** If you use `:set digraph` you can enter `a<BS>:` to give the same result.

These methods will work with any character that needs umlauts, just use `CTRL+K o:` or `CTRL+K u:` respectively.

**Source:** http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could be interested in some Dvorak layouts (mine is [bépo](http://www.bepo.fr), maybe it could suit you?)